# How to mock imported React higher order component using jest & enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, higher-order-components, recompose

I'm writing a module for a project that is a HOC that wraps an application with multiple HOC's (using recompose compose function). Im trying to test that the higher order components are actually wrapping my application.

Example node package containing HOC

```
//withHOC.js
const withHOC = props => WrappedComponent => moreProps => {
    class HOC extends Component {
        //logic
        render () {
            return <WrappedComponent {...moreProps} />
        }
    }
}
export default withHOC
```

My HOC wrapping the passed component using the above namespaced HOC

```
//withWrapper.js
import withHOC from '@HOC/withHOC'
import { compose } from 'recompose'
...etc
const withWrapper = props => WrappedComponent => {
    const innerWrapper => moreProps => (
        <WrappedComponent {...moreProps} />
    );

    const enhance = compose(
        withHOC,
        withHOC1,
        withHOC2,
    );
    return enhance(innerWrapper);
}
export default withWrapper;
```

Test for withWrapper.js

```
//withWrapper.test.js
jest.mock('@HOC/withHOC', () => ({
   withWrapper: (Component) => <div id="test"><Component /></div>
}));
import withWrapper from '@HOC/withHOC' 

const TestApp = () => <div>I am a test element</div>
const EnhancedApp = withWrapper(TestApp)
const wrapper = mount(<EnhancedApp />)
describe('test', () => {
    it('withHOC should wrap the app', () => {
        expect(wrapper.find('#test').length).toEqual(1)
    }
}
```

I am trying to test my application in isolation and am trying to mock each of the HOC's to return a dummy wrapper.
This is where I am currently at with the test and am getting 'TypeError: is not a function' in the compose part of withWrapper.js. I have also tried other methods of mocking but keep getting errors and still havent gotten anywhere.

How would I go about mocking the imported HOC's?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace specific module in testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49062766/replace-specific-module-in-testing)

Answer (score 2):

This is my generic HOC mock. I hope this is what you were looking for.

```js
jest.mock("@HOC", () => {
  return {
    withHOC: () => {
      return (Component) => {
        return (props) => {
          return <Component newProp={jest.fn} {...props} />;
        };
      };
    },
  };
});
```

Comment: How do you do it with `mockImplementation()`?